# Accelerometer not changing values

Tags: android, accelerometer

So I have the code below which I can't get to work. I am trying to have one class (AccelerometerReader) read the values of my phone's accelerometer, and then I call those values in another class (MyGame), which I use to print those values on the screen. Everything in the code seems fine, and I don't get any values, except the values that I print all just say 0.0, and don't change. I know for a fact my phone has an accelerometer too. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks, Owen

**AccelerometerReader Class**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AccelerometerReader extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
 private SensorManager sensorManager;
 float ax,ay,az;   // these are the acceleration in x, y and z axes

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        sensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
   }

   @Override
   public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
       if (event.sensor.getType() != Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
           return;

       if (event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
           ax=event.values[0];
           ay=event.values[1];
           az=event.values[2];
       }
   }


public float getValueX() {
    return ax;
}

public float getValueY() {
    return ay;
}

public float getValueZ() {
    return az;
}
}
```

**Inside MyGame Class**

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    leftWall = new Rect(-100,0,0,canvas.getHeight());
    rightWall = new Rect(canvas.getWidth(), 0, (canvas.getWidth() + 100), canvas.getHeight());
    floor = new Rect(0,canvas.getHeight(),canvas.getWidth(),(canvas.getHeight() + 100));
    ceiling = new Rect(0,-100,canvas.getWidth(),0);

    AccelerometerReader acc = new AccelerometerReader();
    float ax = acc.getValueX();
    float ay = acc.getValueY();
    float az = acc.getValueZ();     

    canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(red,green,blue)); //0 or 51?, 51, 102

    Rect player = new Rect(xPos,yPos,xPos+100,yPos+100);
    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 102, 255));
    canvas.drawRect(player, myPaint);
    myPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    canvas.drawRect(xPos + 5, yPos + 5, xPos + 95, yPos +95, myPaint);
    myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    myPaint.setTextSize(20);
    canvas.drawText("" + Math.round(ySpeed), 75, 50, myPaint);
    canvas.drawText(ax +", "+ ay +", "+ az, 300, 50, myPaint);
    if(gameStarted == false) {
        myPaint.setTextSize(30);
        myPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        canvas.drawText("Touch screen to begin!", canvas.getWidth()/2, canvas.getHeight()/2, myPaint);
    }
    int r = Math.round(rand.nextInt(canvas.getHeight() - 150));
    if(needsRand == true) {
        blockY = r;
        myPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255), rand.nextInt(255)));
    }


    //if(isAlive == true) { 
        Rect block =  new Rect(blockX,blockY,(blockX+100),(blockY+100)); // left, top, right, bottom
        myPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawRect(block, myPaint);
        blockX--;
    //}


    if(player.intersect(leftWall)) {
        xSpeed = Math.abs(xSpeed);
    } else if(player.intersect(rightWall)) { 
        xSpeed = -(xSpeed);
    } else if(player.intersect(floor)) {
        yPos = canvas.getHeight() - 150;
        ySpeed = -(ySpeed)*.75;
    } else if(player.intersect(ceiling)) {
        ySpeed = Math.abs(ySpeed);
    } else if(player.intersect(block)) {
        ySpeed = 0;
    }
    if(blockX <= -100) {
        blockX = canvas.getWidth() + 100;
        needsRand = true;
    } else {
        needsRand = false;
    }

    canvas.drawText("" + r, 300, 100, myPaint);

    physics();
    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {
       public void onCreate() {
              super.onCreate();
              sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
              sm.unregisterListener(this);  
              sm.registerListener(this,sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
       }
       public void onDestroy() {
              super.onDestroy();
              sm.unregisterListener(this);
       }

// Creates a new binder
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return new MyBinder<MyService>(this);
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
       ax=event.values[0];                           
       ay=event.values[1];                           
       az=event.values[2];                
       for (Listener listener : listeners) listener.handleNewAccelValue(this);
}

public interface Listener {
       // Actions to take when a new position has been added to the model
       void handleNewAccelValue(MyService sender);
}

// List of all the ongoing listeners bound to the Model
private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();

// Binds a listener from the View to the Model
public void addListener(Listener listener) {
       this.listeners.add(listener);
}

// Removes a listener from the View to the Model
public void removeListener(Listener listener) {
       this.listeners.remove(listener);
}
```

YourActivity.java

```
public class YourActivity implements MyService.Listener{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        // Binds to the created service
        doBindService();
}

// Creating the controller and the model
private ServiceComputeFinal controller;

// Creates the connection with a MyService service
ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection(){
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
        controller = ((MyBinder<MyService>) binder).getService();           
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        controller = null;
    }   
};

// Binds to the created service
void doBindService(){
    bindService(new Intent(this, MyService.class), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

// And finally recover the accelerometer data that interest you
public void handleNewAccelValue(MyService sender){
    DO_WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_WITH(controller.getAx());
}
```

I gave you all the tools to do what you want. Try to look at this code and understand what it does (it's not really complicated), a ServiceConnection allows the Activity to recover values from the Service and the Listener interface allows the Service to notify the Activity when new values are ready. Feel free to ask anything if needed.

Comment: Sorry to come back with a hand full of answers, I'm getting some errors. First off, int the YourActivity above, I get the error, "ServiceComputeFinal cannot be resolved to a type", along with MyBinder in MyService.java. I'm also wondering how to use these in my MyGame class, since it isn't really an activity. However I open it using another activity called MyGameActivity, is this where I should bind the service? Sorry for the continued questions but I'm pretty new at all this stuff, and I haven't worked with services yet. And Thanks for the above code!

Comment: ServiceComputeFinal -> MyService. Forgot to change this one's name obviously. As for the Activity : if it binded to the Service and has an instance of the MyGame class, you can use is to push accelerometer data to your class. As says the Google API, "Note: Only activities, services, and content providers can bind to a service". To sum up : MyService <-> MyActivity <-> MyGame

Comment: Great! Thanks to your code, and some extra google-ing I was able to get it to work! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The method you use looks really strange to me. You actually pull accelerometer values in your drawing class. It's like, you create an instance of the accelerometer class, then take away his values right away (without waiting for the real accelerometer to actually retrieve values) then try to draw it. That is probably your problem anyway, you draw the starting accelerometer values and don't refresh them when they change. I don't know what's the rest of your code, but if you onDraw is called several time, you just create a new instance of your class and again the values you pull out from it didn't have time to be changed by the sensor readings.

You would better use a push method, implementing a listener interface in the accelerometer class so whenever a new value of acceleration is retrieved, the drawing class is notified and gets the new values, then draw them.

*edit :* I highly recommend you to use a faster delay for your accelerometer (Fastest will do it). Keep in mind the accelero is the less power-consuming of them all.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but I've tried a number of different things only to come to the conclusion that you're right. The values from the accelerometer aren't updating before they are sent to my other class. The problem now is that I can't figure out how to send them while updated. I have also gotten rid of my three methods (getValueX, getValueY, and getValueZ), and just used AccelerationReader.ax. Anymore help would be great! Plus, i'm kind of new, so if you could post at lease some code examples, i'd be great! Sorry, im not trying to sound like im just asking for the whole code, just small parts

Comment: Thing is that as you want the accelerometer values to be retrieved without interruption, you'll want it not to block your Activities. I suggest that you use a Service that will run in the background and update the values. I'll give you a fitting code.